# Why is os.rename not renaming files when the only difference is capitalization?

Tags: python, windows, filesystems

Why is this basic rename script not doing what it should? 
Just trying to capitalize first letter of each word.

```
import glob
import os

for filename in glob.glob("**/*.mp3", recursive = True):
    withcap = str(filename).title()

    print("nc " +(filename))
    print("wc " +(withcap))

    os.rename(filename, withcap)
```

The output from the print is correct but nothing happens at os.rename?

output:

```
nc BLOOD COMMAND - Return Of The Arsonist [Clean].mp3
wc Blood Command - Return Of The Arsonist [Clean].Mp3
```

Comment: Which operating system? Is your filesystem case-sensitive? On Windows or some MacOS installs, the two names are considered identical.

Comment: OS is Windows 10

Comment: ...one thing you can try is making it a two-phase rename -- first to a name that differs in more than just capitalization, then to your final name. Could even be `os.rename(filename, withcap+'.tmp'); os.rename(withcap+'.tmp', withcap)`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy roger that, will not happen again..

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, that did the trick!

Comment: Great! Since it's now tested, I'll write it up as an answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen if you're on an operating system with a case-insensitive filesystem -- like Windows -- where both original and destination names already show us as both existing and pointing to the same file.

A workaround is simply to rename through a temporary name that differs in more than case:

```
for filename in glob.glob("**/*.mp3", recursive = True):
    withcap = str(filename).title()
    os.rename(filename, withcap+'.tmp')
    os.rename(withcap+'.tmp', withcap)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the cause is that you are working with a file system that is case insensitive. It considers the old and new name to be the same, so the "rename" becomes a no-op.

You'll have to do two renames for each file: first to a different, temporary name; then to the actual name with modified capitalization.